# WPF Filtering Datagrid Combobox columns

Tags: c#, wpf

First time posting.  I'm new to both C# and WPF.  I've spent over 15 hours trying to figure this out, and I'm about to quit and start over with Windows Forms instead.  I have a DataGrid with (currently) three columns, but only two are important for this, Type and Subtype.  I have roughly 15 types being filled from an XML file, and each has 2-15 subtypes.  I'm trying to filter (or populate) the second column based on what was selected in the first.

I've tried using DynamicResource on the second column, but it gets overwritten on the next row and clears the first row's selection.  I don't understand Bindings well enough to know how to make them row specific.  I've made both a list and a collection on the C# side that's populated with every subtype of the selected type (and another pair that's populated for each possible Type, and even embedded a subtype collection in my type collection), but I can't figure out how to get any of those into the second column's combobox itemsource without them showing up on every row.

XAML:

```html
 <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Type"
                            ItemsSource="{DynamicResource UnitTypeSource}"
                            SelectedValuePath="TypeString"
                            SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=TypeString, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
                            DisplayMemberPath="TypeString"
                            x:Name="colTypeUnit"/>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Subtype">
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ComboBox
                                        ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AllSubtypes, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow}}"
                                        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                        />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Would appreciate any help, or even just a reference for how this is supposed to work.

Comment: So you want the user to select an item from combobox column 1 and then that will determine the list for combobox column 2?

Comment: Yes.  But I need it to be row independent, so any choice in column 1 should only affect column 2 for that one row.

Comment: Alright yeah, it is a bit complicated but I will give you a working example

Comment: Alright, hope that helps, I am going to be off for a bit but ill check back later if you have any comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with DataGrid and ComboBoxes can get a bit complicated quickly so let us take it one step at a time with some explanations between.  I have given you the full classes for the code in snipets.

To begin I will stick with the MVVM model and use a model-view-viewmmodel to bind data to the DataGrid.  The view model will contain the `Type` and `SubType` value lists, along with the list of rows.  The model class for our row I will call `TypeModel`:

```
public class TypeModel
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string SubType { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know how you will determine what `SubType` is valid for a given `Type` but for this example I will use a dictionary to setup the relations in the view model.

So our view model might look something like:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<TypeModel> Collection { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Type { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, List<string>> SubTypeCollection { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Collection = new ObservableCollection<TypeModel>();
        TypeCollection = new ObservableCollection<string>()
        {
            "Type 1","Type 2","Type 3"
        };

        SubTypeCollection = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>()
        {
            {
                TypeCollection[0], new List<string>()
                {
                    "Type 1 - Sub type 0",
                    "Type 1 - Sub type 1"
                }
            },
            {
                TypeCollection[1], new List<string>()
                {
                    "Type 2 - Sub type 0",
                    "Type 2 - Sub type 1",
                    "Type 2 - Sub type 2",
                    "Type 3 - Sub type 3",
                }
            },
            {
                TypeCollection[2], new List<string>()
                {
                    "Type 3 - Sub type 0",
                    "Type 3 - Sub type 1",
                    "Type 3 - Sub type 2",
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Now lets setup our (initial) view (will be adding to this later):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="600"
        Height="500">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn
                    Header="Type"
                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Type, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> <!-- property changed so we get the change right after we select-->
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style
                            TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter
                                Property="ItemsSource"
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.TypeCollection}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style
                            TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter
                                Property="ItemsSource"
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.TypeCollection}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn
                Header="Sub Type"
                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SubType}">
                <!-- How do we bind to the ItemSource based on the selected type?-->
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

So your fundamental question is how to fill in that commented out section.

There are probably many ways to do this - the easiest in my mind would be to use a `IMultiValueConverter` That takes in two bindings:

1. the selected `Type` string
2. the dictionary `TypeCollection`

So this class will look like this (you really could use this for all `string` to `list<string>` conversions):

```
public class TypeToSubTypesConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null) return null;

        if (values[0] == null || values[0] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) return null;
        var type = values[0].ToString();

        if (values[1] == null || values[1] == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue) return null;
        var subTypeList = values[1] as Dictionary<string, List<string>>;

        if (subTypeList == null) return null;


        return subTypeList[type];

    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now the final steps are to:

1. Add the converter resource to the view
2. Add the mulitibinding to the `value` property of each `setter` for the `ItemsSource` of the second column combobox

So the complete .xaml looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="600"
        Height="500">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TypeToSubTypesConverter
            x:Key="TypeToSubTypesConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn
                    Header="Type"
                    SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Type, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> <!-- property changed so we get the change right after we select-->
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style
                            TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter
                                Property="ItemsSource"
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.TypeCollection}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                        <Style
                            TargetType="ComboBox">
                            <Setter
                                Property="ItemsSource"
                                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.TypeCollection}" />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn>

            <DataGridComboBoxColumn
                Header="Sub Type"
                SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SubType, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"> <!-- property changed so we get the change right after we select-->
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style
                        TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter
                            Property="ItemsSource">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding
                                    Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TypeToSubTypesConverter}">
                                    <Binding
                                        Path="Type" />
                                    <Binding
                                        Path="DataContext.SubTypeCollection"
                                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style
                        TargetType="ComboBox">
                        <Setter
                            Property="ItemsSource">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding
                                    Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TypeToSubTypesConverter}">
                                    <Binding
                                        Path="Type" />
                                    <Binding
                                        Path="DataContext.SubTypeCollection"
                                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" />
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the example, that's exactly what I was looking for! I still don't quite have a great grasp on MVVM, but I can definitely work with this.  Thank you again!